# stopPropagation working in Firefox but not IE or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET user control (ascx) which has a `div` which has its `onclick` open a pop-up. My task is to put a hyperlink into this `div` that goes somewhere else and **not** open the pop-up. My initial problem is that the hyperlink went somewhere else just fine, but it still opened the pop-up. Research brought me to `stopPropagation()`. However, while it appears to be working in Firefox, it doesn't in IE or Chrome. **More to the point, it seems the events themselves aren't wiring up.** I have tried the following on the ASCX:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    /*global $*/
    $("#voucher1").click(function(e) {
        "use strict";
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#voucher2").click(function (e) {
        "use strict";
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*global $*/
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        $("#voucher1").click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $("#voucher2").click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

`voucher1` and `voucher2` are simple `<a id="voucher1" href="blahblah">blah</a>` tags on the control. What am I (or the browser, or both) doing wrong?

Comment: You are supposed to be using both `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` unless you want to stop bubbling of events to its ancestors.  Otherwise just use `return false`

Comment: What is the purpose of using "use strict"; here?

Comment: i really dont see the neeed for `"use strict";` here, not as it is anyway. [Read More](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/)

Comment: @roasted and Read More - suggested by JSLint - really has no other value.

Comment: The bigger problem is in the one sentence in my question "it seems the events themselves aren't wiring up". I can put an `alert('boo!');` after the wireups and *it's not being hit* in IE and Chrome.

Comment: But is your elements "#voucher1" & "#voucher2" in DOM at time you set click handlers or are they added dynamically?

Comment: Including a jsFiddle would probably be a good idea here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @roasted whether they are or not, the `alert` should be hit upon document ready, yes?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer ya sure alert should be fired if inside ready handler. Check your console for error

Comment: @roasted no error, but the weird thing is that it looks like that script block doesn't even exist. Again, not on Firefox, but only on IE and Chrome. Plot thickens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason it didn't work. The framework in which my company renders this page dynamically loads an .aspx into another .aspx (yo, dawg jokes apply here) and it kept my JavaScript from registering at page init, because the child page never really initialized. I found a global JS which gave me access to the child page as it's loading it in and I popped in my stuff there and it works everywhere. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Need to prevent the default action for anchor and make sure the page is completly loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#voucher1").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $("#voucher2").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The bigger problem is in the one sentence in my question "it seems the events themselves aren't wiring up". I can put an `alert('boo!');` after the wireups and *it's not being hit* in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

How many elements are in your containing div? Here is another way to do it that instead of keeping the "cancel popup" logic on the links, puts it on the div itself.

```
$("your div").delegate("*:not(a)", "click", function () { 
    alert("your popup"); 
});
```

This method has the advantage that if you are dynamically adding `<a>` tags to "your div", that since the event handler is attached on "your div", all new children are still wired to the event (or as in your case, not wired to the event).

Full example:

It's best practice to add all jquery event handlers only after the DOM is ready. Luckily, jquery makes this really easy for you as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="your jquery"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#yourdiv").delegate("*:not(a)", "click", function () { 
            alert("your popup"); 
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="yourdiv">
    <span>here but</span>
    <a href="#somewhere">not here</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As per my other comments, where to put this? Seems like any initialization scripts are getting thrown away by IE and Chrome, but not by Firefox.